# Nexus 4 Wifi hotspot, tethering available in OTA-9.1?

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-touch, hot-spot, nexus-4, tethering

I just installed Ubuntu touch on the 16gb LG-E960 and I can find a way to share a internet connection from the phone. Neither wireless or wired. I have tried the stable OTA-9.1 and r24 from the rc channel.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

USB tethering works if you follow the instructios here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus-property-service/+bug/1427697

Instructions from that link...

Prerequisites for your phone:
- Turn on developer mode: "System settings" | "About this phone" | "Developer mode"

- Make the OS image writable by entering on external computer connected via USB:

> phablet-config writable-image

- Make sure that WLAN is turned off.

Steps for fixing tethering (only needed once; repeat after a phone update)

1) unplug the USB cable (on phone side suffices);
   2015-10-15: it seems to have changed now: you must be connected already

2) correct in /usr/bin/tethering:
   "rndis0" should be "usb0"

3) enable rndis:

> sudo android-gadget-service enable rndis

4) enable tethering:

> sudo tethering enable

Note: this might print an error, which can be ignored.

5) If not done before, plug in the USB cable and the computer connects to the internet using a new wired connection.

Instead of steps 2.-4., you can use a script named "fix-tethering" on your phone:

> sh fix-tethering

The file fix-tethering should contain the following 4 lines:

```
  #!

  sudo sed -i -e 's/rndis0/usb0/g' /usr/bin/tethering

  sudo android-gadget-service enable rndis

  sudo tethering enable
```